# QGIS for generic surface documentation setting a custom user scale and CRS

Tags: qgis, scale

I would like to use QGIS for the documentation of generic flat surfaces (so I don't need coordinates relative to a sphere but to a cartesian flat plane) but just overlays some images of surfaces with known dimensions and adding information to them. I would like to open a raster file and set the origin to 0 and the corresponding points to a chosen reference systems so that the units of measurement are right and I can perform some estimation of area and length in the new reference system.

---

I'm trying to set a user-defined projection system using proj4. I'm looking for a suitable CRS for a 2D surface.

At the moment I am opening the raster using the georeferenced and adding some controls to place it on the qgis project. Is there any better approach for using QGIS for documenting generic flat surfaces?

Comment: Any of the Projected Coordinate Systems or "None" should be adequate for a 2D flat surface. The particular CRS you use matters when you convert between reference systems. If you are working in meters or feet, you might one to choose one with a matching unit. If you are working in mm or some other unit, you could define a `+proj=tmerc +units=mm` etc..  You might look into the http://gvellut.github.io/FreehandRasterGeoreferencer/ Or you might write or add a world file (https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wld.html) to specify the pixel->map units before adding the raster.